# jQuery plugin does not run

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am just writing a simple plugin for my own use in a web page. I have html markup like:

```
<ul id="ulview">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

and jQuery plugin code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ulView = function(){
       //console.log(this);
       this.children('li').each(function(){
           alert('test');
       });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and I apply the plugin like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#ulview').ulView();
}
```

For some reason the alert('test') never runs. but I can see the jQuery object has been logged in the console. what do I miss here, thanks for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ulView = function(){
       //console.log(this);
       this.children('li').each(function(){
           alert('test');
       });
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function(){

    $('#ulview').ulView();
});
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/69be3.php

you forgot to execute your function `(jQuery)`

Read [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: I said:  'but I can see the jqury object has been logged in the console.' ...that means everything runs..except the one...

Comment: sorry I have the (jquery) in place. I forgot to place it here

Answer (score 2):

this works :

```
  $.fn.ulView = function(){
       //console.log(this);
       this.children('li').each(function(){
           alert('test');
       });
    }

$('#ulview').ulView();
```

(remove the external "function($) { ")

Answer (score 0):

define the jquery plugin as

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ulView = function(){
       //console.log(this);
       $(this).children('li').each(function(){
           alert('test');
       });
    }
})(jQuery);
```